# IO dispatchers VS KotlinX dispatchers inside an fx block

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

when using IO, in an fx block I can use `continueOn` with `dispatchers.io()` but also `Dispatchers.IO` or I can mix. Is there a preferred way? Is there any difference between the two?

Note: I am also using the coroutines integration to run the IO

```
IO.fx {
        effect { _viewState.postValue(ViewState.Loading) }.bind()
        continueOn(dispatchers().io()) // dispatchers from Arrow
        val repositoryDto: RepositoryDto = effect { service.getRepository() }.bind()
        continueOn(Dispatchers.Default) // Dispatchers from Coroutines
        ViewState.Content(repositoryDto)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no preferred way, and the users can choose to use one, or both together.

While Arrow Fx's pool offers a couple of simple `Executor` pools similar to other functional effect libraries. These  are very efficient with a functional approach.

On the other side KotlinX's dispatcher currently offers more features such as an `EventLoop`, it loads the `Main` dispatcher through `ServiceLoader`  and has testing support.

> I am also using the coroutines integration to run the IO

The KotlinX integration module for Arrow Fx's IO is only meant for integration with structured concurrency `CoroutineScope`.

Comment: "`While also allowing to replace the Main Dispatchers through reflection.`" - How do you replace Disatchers.Main? I'm finding docs to change this. Could you provide some reference/docs?

Comment: Here you go https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/.

`reflection` might have been inaccurate of me, it looks more similar to `RxJava`. It uses a `ServiceLoader` to load by default if you have the correct dependencies on the classpath.